# How can I split this Bootstrap code between header and body section?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, header, sections

I'm working on a static website where I'm allowed to use HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. I have [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/Rgq96HykJ2/sidebar-that-changes-to-navbar) Bootstrap code for a responsive side navbar, but it also contains all the code for the main section as well:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row min-vh-100 flex-column flex-md-row">
    <aside class="col-12 col-md-2 p-0 bg-dark flex-shrink-1">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark flex-md-column flex-row align-items-start py-2">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
                <ul class="flex-md-column flex-row navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0 text-nowrap" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullseye fa-fw"></i> <span class="font-weight-bold">Brand</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart codeply fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Codeply</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star codeply fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link pl-0" href="#"><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Link</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <main class="col bg-faded py-3 flex-grow-1">
        <h2>Example</h2>
        <p>
            This is a Bootstrap 4 example layout that includes a Sidebar menu. On larger screen widths, the Sidebar is on the 
            left side and consumes the entire page height. It's vertically positioned down the screen. On smaller screen widths (like mobile phones and tablets), the Sidebar
            moves to the top of the page, and becomes horizontally positioned across the page like a Navbar. Only icons are shown
            on mobile to limit use of screen real estate.
        </p> 
        <p>
            This Sidebar works using only Bootstrap CSS classes and doesn't require JavaScript. It utilizes the responsive Navbar classes
            to auto-magically switch the Sidebar orientation.
        </p> 
    </main>
</div>
```

How can I split it so that the menu bar goes into `<header>` and the main section into `<body><section>`?

I've tried splitting the code between the tags and adding the BS4 classes to the div in the section tag but that doesn't display the text.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean. I think you forgot some words on your sentence. The menu bar goes into where and the main section goes into where?

Comment: Oh! That’s odd. Thanks for pointing it out. I had used tags but I don’t know why they’re not there! I’ll edit it now. Update: turns out tags don’t show up if not in ``!

Comment: Just make sure when you put a tag to select it and click on the code to make sure its highlighted. Happened to me the other day too :)!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are just forgetting a `</div>` at the end for the container-fluid. When I added that this is the resulting functionality.

[image]

However, **if** the functionality of the gif is not what you want and does not fix the problem for you then I did separate you nav bar into the header and your main into the body which resulted in this:
[image]

Code Demo of separated code into body and header: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2L1ge8/)